# "Whatever" as a determiner

Tags: determiners

At school, I did a Chinese-English translation assignment and translated one of the sentences into English as follows:

> He is always willing to take on **whatever task** assigned to him.

And my teacher changed "whatever" to "any" as in:

> He is always willing to take on **any task** assigned to him.

I asked a friend who is a native-speaker of English for advice, and he said I could use "whatever" as long as I also used "is" behind "task":

> He is willing to take on **whatever** task **is** assigned to him.

I understand that "whatever" can be a conjunction, a pronoun, and a determiner. It seems that my friend treats "whatever task is assigned to him" as a noun clause that functions as the object of preposition "on."
I can understand this explanation.

However, my question lies in whether it is proper to use "whatever" as a determiner in this sentence. I know that both "any" and "whatever" can be determiners.  When analyzing a sentence like "He is always willing to take on any task assigned to him," I think that the noun phrase "any task" is modified by a reduced adjective clause:

> He is always willing to take on any task (which/that is) assigned to him.

If my reasoning stands, I can use "whatever" as a determiner before the noun "task" and use a reduced adjective clause to modify the noun phrase "whatever task":

> He is always willing to take on whatever task (which/that is) assigned to him.

Is my reasoning correct?  I would appreciate it very much if you can tell me what you think. Thank you!

Comment: "Whatever" is always a determinative, either interrogative or relative: _Whatever present you buy for him, he won't be satisfied_ / _I'll accept whatever price you suggest_.

Comment: Note that the 'free choice' use of relative _whatever_, is very close in meaning to the _any_ + integrated relative construction :  _You can buy whatever you like_ ~ _You can buy anything that you like_.

Comment: Note that the noun clause does not function as the object of the preposition "on". "Take on" is a phrasal verb.

Comment: Any dictionary will tell you that 'whatever', like 'any', can be an **adjective**. It will even give you examples exactly like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your friend.

Suppose we reorganised the sentence, like this:

1. He is always willing to take on tasks - any assigned to him.
2. He is always willing to take on tasks - whatever assigned to him.

This shows more clearly that **any** and **whatever** don't function the same way in the sentence. Sentence 1 is correct, on the assumption that **any** is an adjective referring back to the tasks. It is a shortened version of:

- He is always willing to take on tasks - any (task) (which is) assigned to him.

Note that if we expand the sentence we can't just add "is". We need to add "which is". **Any** does not have the function of a relative pronoun in the sentence.

But sentence 2 is not correct. In sentence 2 we need to say, "whatever is assigned to him." **Whatever** functions now as a relative pronoun. It too refers to the tasks, but it is linking to a new clause that needs a verb. Sentence 2 is wrong for the same reason that the next example would be wrong, if the (bracketed) verb was missing in the relative clause.

- He is always willing to take on tasks which (are) assigned to him.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed and clear explanation! Now I know better where I was wrong about how to use "whatever."